# FileStream says it cant find a part of the path

Tags: c#, itext, filestream

[image]So i have this console app that looks through a folder for files, this folder only has `.tiff` images and the whole point of the app is convert them all into pdf files and finally merge them, and so I have this `foreach` cycle

```
        foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/tferreira/Desktop/TIF_MarcadAgua"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(path); // full path
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)); // file name

            Escrever("A fazer pdf");

            imagens.Add(path.ToUpper().Replace("A.TIF", "A.PDF").Replace("A.tif", "A.PDF"));
            FazerPdf(path);
            if (File.Exists(path.ToUpper().Replace("A.TIF", "B.TIF")))
            {
                imagens.Add(path.ToUpper().Replace("A.TIF", "B.PDF"));

                FazerPdf(path.ToUpper().Replace("A.TIF", "B.TIF"));
            }
            Escrever("O pdf foi gerado com sucesso. Caminho : " + path.ToUpper().Replace("A.TIF", "A.PDF").Replace("A.tif", "A.PDF"));

            Escrever("Vai fazer o merge de todos os pdfs gerados.");

            PdfMerge pm = new PdfMerge();
            foreach (string imagem in imagens)
            {
                pm.AddDocument(imagem);
                npages++;
            }
        }
```

And what is does is run trough the folder getting all the files and storing the path in that var path variable.

But when it´s actually time to make the pdf it gives that error i mentioned up top.

The line the error happens is this the fazerPDF funtion, thats where the pdf is made, since its a filepath error i will only show the error line since it keeps things easy to see.

```
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Replace("TIF", "PDF"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // some code 
    }
```

Things i know, the images do exist, the folder does exist.
Thanks for the help, if i myself find out what it is ill post a answer.

EDIT:

fazerPDF function

```
static public void FazerPdf(string Path)
    {
        string newPath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(Path, ".pdf");
        if (!File.Exists(Path.Replace("TIF", "PDF")))
          
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(newPath.Replace("TIF", "PDF"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
```

Comment: can you add some screenshot of actual error , that might help to understand better.

Comment: @ashmabi Screenshot, but its in Portuguese, but its says it can´t find part of the path to that image.

Comment: Does the directory `C:/Users/tferreira/Desktop/PDF_MarcadAgua` (note PDF not TIF) exist?

Comment: @Llama wait how have i not seen that, where did that comeFrom i did not made any line like that it should be tif not pdf

Comment: `.Replace("TIF", "PDF")` will replace any instance of `TIF` in the string with `PDF`. So `"This is a nice TIF file. Do you like TIF files?".Replace("TIF", "PDF")` would return `"This is a nice PDF file. Do you like PDF files?"`.

Comment: You can probably use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=net-5.0) if you only want to replace the extension, and then simply add `.pdf` to the end.

Comment: @Llama the Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension is not showing as a usable line, can you please make a response?

Comment: Can you confirm that you only want to change the file extension from .TIF to .PDF? P.S. I think it's not showing as a usable line because your variable is called `Path`, so it's getting confused.

Comment: @Llama i want to convert this .tiff images into pdf´s and then merge those pdf´s into a single one.

Comment: debug and check what exactly you are getting value for `Path` variable, it must be full string value of your target folder.

Comment: @ashmabi That's visible in the screenshot.

Comment: @Llama after the fazerPDF function it stays the same, "something.TIF", it didnt change to .pdf

Comment: oh okay you already posted a screenshot, looks like for me its not reflected yet since had edited post while back and yet to be approved.

Comment: @ashmabi approved and added the screenshot

Comment: @Llama yes, fazerPDF is where the pdf is actually made and that error as occuring, the fileStream one

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something then. Again: please can you confirm if you only want to change the file extension from .TIF to .PDF in `Path`, rather than replacing ANY instance of "TIF" in the `Path` string with "PDF"? Or can you produce a more minimal example that's not clouded by other things you're doing?

Comment: @Llama i only want to change the extension, not the names, so i can merge all of them later into one single pdf file

Comment: So the code I've provided as an answer does exactly that: It takes a path string to a file with extension `.tif` and then produces a new path string to a file with extension `.pdf`.

Comment: @Llama, yes and i tried it out, and it didn´t work for me as the file still stays as a .tif, ill edit my post and maybe we can find out what i did wrong.

Comment: "The file still stays as TIF". Where are you seing this? You're not renaming a file anywhere, you're creating a new file.

Comment: @Llama i´m seeing this after it leaves the FazerPDF function and goes back to static void main/ edited the post.

Comment: 1) You're passing a copy of `path` into `FazerPDF`. 2) We're creating a new `string newPath` within `FazerPDF`. You can't expect any "changes" to these strings to be reflected outside the method.

Comment: i wonder how its taking Path as a variable without compile error, can you try changing `Path` to some other variable name say ex: `targetPath` and give a try.

Comment: @ashmabi Why would you expect a compiler error?

Comment: @ashmabi ill change the variable Path to targetPath then

Comment: OP: If you want to change it in the parent method, then I suggest modifying `FazerPdf` to take two strings: `currentPath` and `newPath`. Then do the extension change in your other method that calls `FazerPdf`.

Comment: @Llama then i need to bring this newPath variable with me when it gets out of fazerPDF right?

Comment: Yes, or create it outside fazerPDF and pass it in as a second parameter.

Comment: `imagens.Add(path.ToUpper().Replace("A.TIF", "A.PDF").Replace("A.tif", "A.PDF")` Umm, that second replace isn't doing anything.

Comment: i made the function fazerPDF to take two string one called path and one called NewPath

Comment: @mjwills oh really?

Comment: @Tiago mjwills means that you're converting the string to uppercase, so there will never be an `A.tif`.

Comment: @Llama oh ok, i get it now

Comment: @Llama i made those changes, and it still doesen´t work

Comment: Be specific. What does that mean? Have you checked that the paths you're passing to `FazerPdf` are correct? Set a breakpoint and inspect them.

Comment: @Llama alright i will

Comment: @Llama ok so im passing in here static public void FazerPdf(string Path, string newPath) in path this Setembro_000.tif and in newPath this C:/Users/tferreira/Desktop/TIF_MarcadAgua\Setembro_000.tif

Comment: @Llama forget it, thank you for the help, i was able to do it, your answer is the right one, thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be this line:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Replace("TIF", "PDF"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
```

This will replace all instances of `"TIF"` in `Path` with `"PDF"`, no matter where they appear. For example:

```
c:\TIFs\IlikeTIFfiles\MyTIF.TIF
```

Would become:

```
c:\PDFs\IlikePDFfiles\MyPDF.PDF
```

If you simply want to replace the file extension part of the path, you can use [`Path.ChangeExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=net-5.0) to cut off the old extension and add the new one:

```
string newPath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".pdf");
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
```

Taking the example above, `@"c:\TIFs\IlikeTIFfiles\MyTIF.TIF"` would become `@"c:\TIFs\IlikeTIFfiles\MyTIF.pdf"`

[See it in action](https://rextester.com/JJXSKE34958).